# Is it possible to refer the field in the Database table but not in the Entity?

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, field

I have an entity called `Person` which refers to the table `person`.
This Person entity does not have all the fields from the person table.

For example, Person entity does not have zipcode and email, which exists in person table.

Now from a query, I get a list of Person entities. I need to generate another query based on the values from these Person entities. But I need to use `zipcode` and `email` along with other Person entity fields. Is this possible at all? (I know its a wild thought)

Is it possible to refer entity fields and fields (zipcode and email) from the table together?

Note: The two fields zipcode and email are omitted in the Person entity for a reason, but need them in a different query.

Comment: just create an sql query.

Comment: Not sure what you mean. I have Person entities on hand and I need to build a query to get other entities based on the values from Person entity. I cannot simply write query directly on person table.

Comment: Hibernate only performs queries on mapped entities and their fields. You're going to have to write your own SQL query.

Comment: So I guess there is no way to mix them, Entities with fields directly from the table. Correct?

Comment: Some providers like EclipseLink allow adding query keys - mappings to fields that can be used in queries, but do not exist in the entity.  This concept isn't in JPA and so would be provider specific: http://wiki.eclipse.org/EclipseLink/UserGuide/JPA/Basic_JPA_Development/Querying/Query_Keys  if that is not possible in your provider, you will need to frame your query in SQL, or add a mapping to the entity that is inaccessible to the application.

Answer (score 0):

Yes this is possible. You can use EntityManager createNativeQuery:

```
EntityManager em = // obtain em somehow..
String sql = "select id, name from person where zipcode = '10000' and email = 'bob@email.com";
List<Person> persons = em.createNativeQuery(sql, Person.class).getResultList();
```

Note that only fields mapped to the entity class can be selected. In most cases this defeats the purpose of using JPA/Hibernate in the first place.

Comment: I guess you mis-understood my question. I have Person Entities on hand already and I need to build a query to get other entities (ex: address) based on some non-existent fields from Person entity (but existing in person table).

Comment: In which case the answer is no because there's no way you can retrieve information from unmapped fields/column. The only way you can achieve it is by using native SQL combined with join. For example if you have Pet entity where a person can own one-to-many pets, you can search pet owned by person in zipcode 10000 by doing `select e.* from person p join pet e on p.id = e.person_id where p.zipcode = '10000'`. This again defeats the purpose of ORM